# excel, make a checkbox undo operation when de-selected

Tags: excel, vba

I have a checkbox which copies 5 cells of a address into 5 cells below if the project address is the same as the correspondence address.
here is the code I have:

```
Sub copy_address()
'
' copy_address Macro
'
    Range("D5:G5").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Range("D11:G11").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Range("D6:G6").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    Range("D12:G12").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Range("D7:G7").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    Range("D13:G13").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Range("D8:G8").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    Range("D14:G14").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Range("F9:G9").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    Range("F15:G15").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste

    SendKeys "{ESC}"

    ActiveSheet.Range("D17").Select

End Sub
```

But what it does not do is undo the copy and paste when de-selected. In fact it carries out the copy and paste operation weather the box is ticked or un-ticked.

Comment: Can you edit your question to include the code which calls this routine please.

Comment: I think the checkbox is assigned to the copy_address sub. which is why it runs when he checks or un-checks the check box.

Answer (score 0):

There is no mention in your code of any checkbox or its current state (aka .Value). Typically, after putting an ActiveX checkbox on the worksheet, you would use Design Mode and right-click it for the **View Code** command.

Once on the worksheet's code sheet in the VBE, modify the on-click handler to something like this.

```
Private Sub CheckBox1_Click()
    If CheckBox1.Value Then
        Range("D5:G8").Copy Destination:=Range("D11")
        Range("F9:G9").Copy Destination:=Range("F15")
    Else
        Range("D11:G14").ClearContents
        Range("F15:G15").ClearContents
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Or you can try this if you want to keep the already assigned copy_address sub.

```
Sub copy_address()
'
' copy_address Macro
If ActiveSheet.Shapes("Check Box 1").ControlFormat.Value = 1 Then
    ActiveSheet.Range("D5:G8").Copy Destination:=ActiveSheet.Range("D11:G14")
    ActiveSheet.Range("F9:G9").Copy Destination:=ActiveSheet.Range("F15:G15")
Else
    ActiveSheet.Range("D11:G15").ClearContents
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Many thanks Guys this works perfectly. Much appreciated.